# How to fix the insecurity of disabled ASP.NET controls, generically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, webforms

So I just came across a huge security hole I was never really aware of:

Usualy when I set `Enabled = false` on any control, I would assume it will not allow me to modify the value on the control at all. However, when the client removes the markup `disabled="disabled"` as well as the class `aspNetDisabled`, thus posting a different value, ASP.NET will accept it, even when my control is disabled on server side.

Example ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbUsername" runat="server" CssClass="form-control focus-popover required" MaxLength="32" Enabled="false" Text="test" />
<asp:Button ID="bSave" runat="server" CssClass="bb btn btn-primary btn-block" Text="Submit" OnClick="bSave_Click" />
```

Example Code-Behind:

```
protected void bSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.Write(this.tbUsername.Text); // BREAKPOINT HERE
}
```

After further inspection I've found out I can set `ReadOnly = true` that will reset the value no matter what was posted. `ReadOnly` is not available on all `WebControl`s, though.

Is there any generic way to force to reset the value when it's disabled? Setting `submitdisabledcontrols="false"` on the `form` has no effect.

Btw, Would it be safe to ask for `Enabled` before reading the value, or can `Enabled` be changed by the client on the server-side? I.e. is `if(this.tbUsername.Enabled) obj.Username = this.tbUsername.Text;` safe to fetch the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never trust a UI.

A savvy user can always modify your user interface or create their own. Data crossing the wire can be tampered with in flight.

The business logic layer needs to validate all data.

> I decide what controls are editable depending on the permission rights of the user who is accessing the website

You can open the developer tools in a browser (e.g. press F12 on IE/Edge) and remove the read-only flag on any control. It's insufficient if you care about a savvy user bypassing your permission system.

Comment: Of course the correct answer but more easily said than done with such a thick abstraction layer as classic ASP.NET provides... good luck to the OP with that! ;)

Comment: This answer is so true, it should be the job of the BLL. The laziness tries to rule me again. The thing is, I decide what controls are editable depending on the permission rights of the user who is accessing the website. My BLL validates the values of my object, but does not implement any permission system to validate the input based on the user who submits the object. Having my BLL doing all these things makes it just ................. so much heavier.

Comment: @modiX, I switched to ASP.NET MVC when that came out and never looked back. The heaviness, complexity, client-unfriedliness etc. of ASP.NET webforms was never my cup of tea and seeing this kind of posts just confirms my choice. Good luck with the fix!

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer to suit my problem even further. In fact, when I set a control to `Enabled = false` on server-side I can modify the control as much as I want on the client side, the user cannot change `Enabled` to become `true` after postback on server-side, even when removing `disabled` and `readonly` attributes of the control on client-side. So when I fetch the data I could check for `Enabled == true` before I read the value from it. ASP.NET stores this information in the ViewState. Now the ViewState is stored in the database and not at the client. This should be safe, I think